# Infer type from object property

Tags: typescript, typing

Is it possible to create a generic function that infers the type from the "external" object property?

Imagine something like this:

```
const resolversMap: {
  overallRankingPlacement: (issuer: number, args: Record<string, any>, context: Record<string, any>) => Promise<number>;
} = {
  overallRankingPlacement: createResolver((issuer, args, context) => {
    return 0;
  }),
};

function createResolver<T extends () => void>(resolverFn: T): ReturnType<T> {
  return (...args) => {
    // Some additional logic...
    resolverFn(...args);
  };
}
```

The goal would be so that the function returned by `createResolver` would match the exact return of "overallRankingPlacement" and the arguments passed to it would match just the same—kind of mirroring/proxying everything in regards to type.

Comment: Your code contains  invalid syntax, pls fix it

Comment: Where exactly? Runs good from here, but typings are definitely broken since those are the ones I don't know how to do correctly

Comment: ohh, my bad, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using generic parameters for both the argument-array and the result type. Something like this will work:

```
function createResolver<Args extends unknown[], Res>(
  resolverFn: (...args: Args) => Res
): (...args: Args) => Res {
  return (...args: Args) => {
    // Some additional logic...
    return resolverFn(...args);
  };
}
```

The `resolversMap` example above will still fail though, as the `overallRankingPlacement` function returns a promise, whereas the argument to `createResolver` doesn't. You can fix it by removing `Promise` from the return type or passing an asynchronous function to `createResolver` to get the types in line.

Maybe what you're looking for is a `createResolver` that returns an async function? If so, you could add a `Promise` and an `async` to the function above and get:

```
function createAsyncResolver<Args extends unknown[], Res>(
  resolverFn: (...args: Args) => Res
): (...args: Args) => Promise<Res> {
  return async (...args: Args) => {
    // Some additional async logic...
    return resolverFn(...args);
  };
}
```

This version will work correctly with your sample `resolversMap`.

It may be worth noting that wrapping functions like this does not handle overloaded functions well. Only the last overload is retained, so for

```
function overloaded(x: number): number
function overloaded(x: string): string
function overloaded(x: number | string) {
    return x
}
```

the wrapped function will only be from `string` to `string`:

```
const unfortunatelyNotOverloaded = createResolver(overloaded)
const ok = unfortunatelyNotOverloaded('ok') // inferred type: string
const fail = unfortunatelyNotOverloaded(1) 
// ERROR: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I don't think there's any way around this yet, and maybe it won't even get supported at all.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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)

Comment: Nice solution, as always. Btw, you can avoid using overloads just with extra generic: `const overloaded = <T,>(x: T) => x`

Comment: Merci! The overloaded function was just a basic example to show that the overloaded signatures aren't preserved, but you're absolutely right that this specific one can be written with generics.

Comment: I did not want to correct You. It was just a tip for other people who will read your answer

Comment: Thanks @Oblosys. I ended up with the same solution eventually. Appreciate it!